Invariant theory (first fundamental theorem) for a direct sum of two fundamental representations
Let $G$ be a simple reductive group over $\mathbb C$, e.g. $G=\mathrm{SO}(V)$ is a special orthogonal group.
Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two irreducible representations of $G$. Assume both $W_i$ are fundamental representations, e.g. $W_1=V, W_2=\wedge^2V$ for $G=\mathrm{SO}(V)$ (assuming $\dim V \geq 7$).
Let $W=W_1 \oplus W_2$. Is there an explicit description of the GIT quotient $W \to W // G$ (e.g. dimension, singularity, flatness) at least for $G=\mathrm{SO}(V)$? Could we find explicit generators of the ring of invariants $\mathbb C[W]^G$?
